# Как увеличить время выполнения php скрипта?

Tags: php

Через сторонний сервис создаю скриншоты сайтов с помощью следующего кода

```
function upload_image($img){

$filename = "/var/www/images/$img.jpeg";

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "Файл $img существует"; // Чем заменить, чтобы пропустить?
        } else {
        $url = "http://mini.s-shot.ru/1024x768/300/jpeg/?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$img";
        $path = "/var/www/images/$img.jpeg";
        file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($url));
    }

}

$img = upload_image("mw9WcQo6aIY");
```

Чтобы не скачивать изображения после каждого выполнения скрипта, делаю проверку на наличие файла в папке и если его нет, выполняю скрипт - сохраняю картинку.

Столкнулся с проблемой, скрипт выполняется прежде чем сервис успевает создать скриншот, в результате, в большинстве случаев, картинка сохраняется в папке но имеет 0 B размер, т.е. пустая.

Свою задачу скрипт не выполняет.

Как увеличить время выполнения скрипта, чтобы скриншот успевал создаться?

Чем заменить строку echo `"Файл $img существует";`, можно просто закомментировать?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что вам нужно нечто вроде sleep()? Т.е., она останавливает выполнение скрипта на указанное количество секунд. Но я не уверен, что проблема именно в этом, пробуйте:

```
function upload_image($img){
    $filename = "/var/www/images/$img.jpeg";

    if (! file_exists($filename)) {
        $url = "http://mini.s-shot.ru/1024x768/300/jpeg/?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$img";
        $path = "/var/www/images/$img.jpeg";
        $content = file_get_contents($url);
        sleep(2);
        file_put_contents($path, $content);
    }
}

$img = upload_image("mw9WcQo6aIY");
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте данную функцию:

```
set_time_limit(60);
```

В скобках указано количество секунд, которое пройдет, прежде чем выполнение скрипта, будет принудительно завершено.

Так же, возможно изменить данный параметр изменив параметр `max_execution_time` в `php.ini`:

```
max_execution_time 60
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло. Данный параметр `set_time_limit(300);` разрешает выполнять скрипт долго но не тормозит его выполнение. Я поставил значение 300, скрипт выполнился за секунду и сохранил пустой файл.